# Запятая перед "согласно"

Tags: пунктуация

Тут задавался вопрос о том, нужно ли ставить запятую после оборота с "согласно", а нужна ли запятая перед в подобном предложении: "Все это происходит(,) согласно его планам"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь - точно нет. Это никак не вводный оборот, т.к. изятие без потери смысла невозможно. Причин для обособления нет.

Хотя даже в том случае, когда оборот имеет признаки вводного (согласно его планам(,) должно было произойти то-то и то-то) обособление факультативно.

Comment: Согласно его планам, должно то-то произойти.
Запятая факультативна. Согласно его планам - это обстоятельственный оборот «предлог + существительное».

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае *согласно* является производным предлогом. *Все происходит по его планам.*  Запятая не нужна.

Comment: Разве тот факт, что "согласно" здесь предлог, сам по себе исключает обособление присоединяемого оборота?

Comment: Я не о том. Просто замена производного предлога на непроизводный в данном случае наглядно показывает ненужность запятой.

Comment: ммм... С этим согласен. Только как бы это попонятнее выразить в тексте ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно его планам, должно то-то произойти.

Постановка запятой возможна, однако не обязательна.

Вариант без запятой

Согласно его планам должно то-то произойти. Отсутствие запятой подчеркнет, что то-то должно произойти именно согласно его планам.

Вариант с запятой - то-то должно произойти в любом случае и при этом это согласуется с его планами.

Comment: Иначе говоря, непостановка запятой указывает на то, что такие сочетания являются в предложении обстоятельствами, без которых высказывание лишается смысла, вкладываемого в него говорящим, а ее постановка указывает на дополнительный статус подобной конструкции.

Answer (score 0):

Помню, что Розенталь такие конструкции с предлогами "согласно, вопреки, вместо, в соответствии ..." относит к дополнению как члену предложения и предлагает обособлять при достаточной распространенности. В заданном вопросе "согласно плану" - нераспространенное дополнение, поэтому запятая не нужна.

Comment: Обособление любой конструкции - выделение с целью подчеркнуть ее особый грамматический статус или особую смысловую нагруженность.

Смысловая нагрузка такого оборота повышается при его расположении в начале предложения, перед сказуемым или в значительном отдалении от него, при значительной распространенности обстоятельственного оборота, в зависимости от стилистической задачи, 
при наличии синтаксической несочетаемости связанных по смыслу слов.

Comment: Обороты с производными предлогами и предложными сочетаниями обязательно обособляются, если они располагаются между подлежащим и сказуемым: разрыв их непосредственной связи и способствует выделению оборотов. 
В других позициях такие обороты могут не обособляться (без необходимости подчеркивания). Ср.: 
Согласно приказу группа расформирована. 
— Группа, согласно приказу, расформирована;

Answer (score 0):

Начала читать "tips on writing great answers" и в первом же абзаце наткнулась на слово "бе**з**корыстно". Дальше читать не стала ;-)…

Тем не менее отвечаю.

Граждане, из-за чего вы здесь копья ломаете? У автора вопроса чётко написано: "Все это происходит(,) согласно его планам"! При чём здесь "согласно его планам(,) должно было произойти то-то и то-то"? Конструкция, о которой спрашивают, имеет вполне конкретный смысл: "Все это происходит по его планам", "Все это происходит в соответствии с его планами". Ни о какой запятой речи быть не может (ни опционно, ни факультативно!).

Вот ссылка: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_693

Там сказано применительно к ситуации с аналогичным контекстом:

"Оборот с предлогом «согласно» не выделяется запятыми, если он является частью сказуемого или тесно связан со сказуемым по смыслу.

*В комнате Коли вечер наступал согласно законам природы, поскольку свет там давно не горел.* Л. Петрушевская, Козел Ваня".

Comment: Начала читать "tips on writing great answers" - это где? И зачем столько эмоций? Отвечать надо спокойно и бе**с**пристрастно.

Comment: Кстати, вопросу 3,5 года. Все уже давно забыли про копья.